# How to display the Close caption in bottom of the video screen?

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I am working on a Roku app using Scene Graph components. In my application, closed captions (subtitles) are showing on top of the video screen. However I want to display them on the bottom of the video screen.

Please provide suggestions to resolve it.

Comment: https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Closed+Caption+Support

Comment: Thanks for reply but this link only help bright script, i am using scene graph.

Comment: https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Playing+Videos#PlayingVideos-ConfiguringClosedCaptions

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Video node](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Video) in fullscreen, closed captions will be shown automatically if you enable them in options dialog. Also they should be present in stream.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Yes when we uses video node in full screen, closed captions will be show automatically but i want to show close captions in bottom of screen not a top and middle.

Answer (score 0):

As for me the best solution for your problem is to parse the closed captions and show closed captions where you want it. Also, you will be able to set any font for it and add another customisation.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Please provide any references how to customization close captions in Scene Graph.

Comment: @vijaykumar Well, first of all you need to clarify what closed captions format are you using. After that you will need to read more about it's structure and try to parse it.